# unable of get output from a 2d vector because of runtime error

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, subscript-operator

i am writing a program that will intake value of a 2 dimensional vector and provide them a output.But,i am getting a runtime error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
// your code goes here
vector<vector<int> > vec;
vec[0].push_back(1);
vec[0].push_back(2);
vec[0].push_back(13);

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    cout<<vec[0][i]<<" ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: `vec` starts out *empty*. Any indexing into `vec` leads to *undefined behavior*-

Comment: And please take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) as well as [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

Your vector of vectors is empty. You can't do `vec[0].push_back(1);` because `vec[0]` doesn't exist. You can solve that problem by making your vector of vectors with a size of at least `1` by specifying that in the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Change this

```
vector<vector<int> > vec;
```

To this:

```
vector<vector<int> > vec(1);
```

Alternatively you could `push_back` a vector into your vector of vectors:

```
vec.push_back(std::vector<int>());
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You declared an empty vector

```
vector<vector<int> > vec;
```

So you may not use the subscript operator like

```
vec[0].push_back(1);
```

You could declare the vector having at least one element of the type `std::vector<int>` like

```
vector<vector<int> > vec( 1 );
```

In any case you could declare and initialize the vector in one statement as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = { 1, { 1, 2, 13 } };

    for ( const auto &item : vec[0] ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 13
```

Answer (score 0):

extending the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59932594/4139593),

you even can allocate a row `vector` and add to the main `vector`. with which you can add new the rows,

```
int main() {           
    vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(13);

    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    vec.push_back(v1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << vec[0][i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```